# Is there a simple example on iconv transliteration of from-language-to-language for c?

Tags: c, text, internationalization, iconv

Say we have the simple scenario, a string of a language, say French.

And we want that French to be converted to ASCII in a transliterated form.

How can it be done in C in the simplest way?

Also is there's a completely different way, irrelevant to iconv, ideally multiplatform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want multiplatform, `iconv` is not the right tool. Transliteration is a GNU-specific extension. In general, transliteration is a hard problem, and the GNU `iconv` implementation is only sufficient for trivial cases. How a non-ASCII character gets transliterated is not a property of the character but of the language of the text and how it's being used. For instance, should "日" become "ri" or "ni" or something else entirely? Or if you want to stick with Latin-based languages, should "ö" become "o" or "oe"? Expanding to other non-Latin scripts, transliterating most Indic languages is fairly straightforward, but transliterating Thai requires some reordering of characters and transliterating Tibetan requires parsing whole syllables and identifying which letters are in root/prefix/suffix/etc. roles.

In my opinion, the best answer to "How do I transliterate to ASCII?" for *most software programs* is: **don't**. Instead fix whatever bugs or intentionally-English-centric policies made you want ASCII in the first place. The only software that should really be doing transliteration is highly-linguistically-aware software facilitating search or interpretation of texts not in the user's own native language.

Comment: The problem I have is a third application that doesn't provide unicode in text (a mere game). But I'll accept the answer since it's linguistically very important to not wreck languages.